# Retrieving multiple but not all fields but same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to populate a Rota table for drivers from an excel document where the trip id numbers are stored.

on uploading into the application I need it to fetch the start time of that run from the runs table for each day via SP

This part isn't a problem and all works fine the issue begins when certain days are '0' (Day Off) so unless the driver is in for everyday of the week the data doesn't return.

I know this isn't very attractive SQL but its just a quick mock-up to explain the problem.

Here is the T-SQL

```
(   
@runid0 as int = 0,
@runid1 as int = 0,
@runid2 as int = 0,
@runid3 as int = 0,
@runid4 as int = 0,
@runid5 as int = 0,
@runid6 as int = 0,
@siteid as int

)
AS
declare @effectivedate0 as datetime
declare @effectivedate1 as datetime
declare @effectivedate2 as datetime
declare @effectivedate3 as datetime
declare @effectivedate4 as datetime
declare @effectivedate5 as datetime
declare @effectivedate6 as datetime

set @effectivedate0 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID0 order by effective_from DESC)
set @effectivedate1 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunId1 order by effective_from DESC)
set @effectivedate2 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID2 order by effective_from DESC)
set @effectivedate3 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID3 order by effective_from DESC)
set @effectivedate4 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID4 order by effective_from DESC)
set @effectivedate5 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID5 order by effective_from DESC)
set @effectivedate6 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM db_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID6 order by effective_from DESC)

Select * From 
    (SELECT arrival as arr0 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid0 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate0) a 
  Cross Join
    (SELECT arrival as arr1 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid1 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate1) b 
  Cross Join
    (SELECT arrival as arr2 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid2 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate2) c 
  Cross Join
    (SELECT arrival as arr3 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid3 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate3) d 
  Cross Join
    (SELECT arrival as arr4 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid4 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate4) e 
  Cross Join
    (SELECT arrival as arr5 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid5 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate5) f 
  Cross Join
    (SELECT arrival as arr6 from db_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid6 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate6) g

RETURN
```

Comment: This is just returning 1 row with 7 columns, one value for each of the @runids and the result is 0 rows because one of the result sets is empty? Could you change the cross apply pattern to be union alls, and then pivot the result into columns?

Comment: Hi yes 1 row with the 7 columns is what im looking for but if the runid is 0 then i need that column to be blank such as days sun to wed working 
` ---0------1-------2------3--------4--------5-------6--`
`10:00  12:00 10:00 10:00    -          -          -   `
never used the pivot function before i'll do a bit of reading and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the union pivot idea i couldn't get working but i did find another method which may help others where pivot doesn't work for them either.

Just declare variables for each day and run the singular queries for each variable, dump them in a temp table and select * the table.

is it going to more efficient then a combined query, probably not. 
is it the cleanest / most concise approach, definitely not.
does it do the job yes.

if any one wishes to post a better version obviously please do so.

```
(   
@runid0 as int = 0,
@runid1 as int = 0,
@runid2 as int = 0,
@runid3 as int = 0,
@runid4 as int = 0,
@runid5 as int = 0,
@runid6 as int = 0,
@siteid as int

)
```

AS
    declare @effectivedate0 as datetime
    declare @effectivedate1 as datetime
    declare @effectivedate2 as datetime
    declare @effectivedate3 as datetime
    declare @effectivedate4 as datetime
    declare @effectivedate5 as datetime
    declare @effectivedate6 as datetime
    declare @arr0 as varchar(5)
    declare @arr1 as varchar(5)
    declare @arr2 as varchar(5)
    declare @arr3 as varchar(5)
    declare @arr4 as varchar(5)
    declare @arr5 as varchar(5)
    declare @arr6 as varchar(5)

```
Declare @table Table ( day0 varchar(5), day1 varchar(5), day2 varchar(5), day3 varchar(5), day4 varchar(5), day5 varchar(5), day6 varchar(5))

BEGIN
set @effectivedate0 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID0 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr0 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid0 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate0)
END
BEGIN
set @effectivedate1 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunId1 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr1 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid1 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate1)
END
BEGIN
set @effectivedate2 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID2 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr2 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid2 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate2)
END
BEGIN
set @effectivedate3 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID3 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr3 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid3 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate3)
END
BEGIN
set @effectivedate4 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID4 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr4 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid4 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate4)
END
BEGIN
set @effectivedate5 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID5 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr5 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid5 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate5)
END
BEGIN
set @effectivedate6 = (Select TOP 1 effective_from FROM dbo_t_run_plan WHERE effective_from <= GetDATE() AND site_id=@siteid AND run_id=@RunID6 order by effective_from DESC)
set @arr6 = (SELECT arrival as arr from dbo_t_run_orders where run_id = @runid6 and site_id=@siteid and trip_no=1 and visit_order = 1 and effective_from = @effectivedate6)
END

insert into @table values (@arr0,@arr1,@arr2,@arr3,@arr4,@arr5,@arr6)

select * from @table



RETURN
```

Comment: Yes this works too, but instead of having a table, you could just do select @arr0, + the other variables..  -- and by the way the begin + end blocks don't really do anything there, except make it harder to read.

Comment: Cool thanks for that, admittedly the begin ends are just a bad habbit i picked up when learning someone told me basically if you have more then one query encapsulate it.